# From which collection is this hadith taken?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, source-identification, reference-request, zina

> "A society given to Zina falls prey to severe famine and a society immersed in transaction of bribes is engulfed with fear and terror "(Musnad Ahmad (allegedly))

--- Okay so I got this hadith from my textbook, but I don't trust it. That's why I ask. Does any authentic hadith of this sort exist? If yes, can someone please give the references?

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide/share the source of your quote?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I got it from my textbook, it didn’t mention the number, but it mentioned the name of the collection----- Musnad Ahmad, but I don't trust it, that's why I ask

Comment: why don't you trust it? I mean the hadith in original text is in Arabic we strongly need any information which is available like the narrator etc. Musnad Ahmad is a source in which you may find around 70‰ of all sunni ahadith.

Comment: @Medi1Saif What can I do now, okay I'll edit the question

Comment: @Medi1Saif Did you find it?